# PHP MySQL If else Statement

Tags: php, mysql, if-statement

I have the following code

```
if(mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0)
{
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
    {
    $output .= '
                            <div class="col-md-3">
                                <div class="single-post">
                                    <img src="img/cars/'.$row["fahrzeugBild"].'.jpg" alt="">
                                    <h4><span class="author-name">Modell: '.$row["fahrzeugName"].'</span></h4>
```

How is it possible getting $output into If else statement? 
So if $row is empty it should return nothing.

```
if(mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0)
{
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
    {
    $output .= '
echo    <div class="col-md-3">
echo    <div class="single-post">
If .$row["fahrzeugBild"] empty then
nothing
else
echo    <img src="img/cars/'.$row["fahrzeugBild"].'.jpg" alt="">

If .$row["fahrzeugName"] empty then
nothing
else
echo    <h4><span class="author-name">Modell: '.$row["fahrzeugName"].'</span></h4>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've made a pretty good effort and it shows in the details of your question.

There are a couple of places you might use an if statement, depending on what you mean.

OK, I think I understand now. You want the individual elements of the $row to control individual elements in additions to the $output.

That'll require a series of checks, sort of like you've done, but not inside the string itself.

```php
if(mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0) {
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
      if ($row == "") {
       // do one thing
      } else {
        $output .= '<div class="col-md-3"><div class="single-post">';
        if ($row["fahrzeugBild"] !== "") {
          $output .= '<img src="img/cars/'.$row["fahrzeugBild"].'.jpg" alt="">';
        }
        if ($row["fahrzeugName"] !== "") {
          $output .= '<h4><span class="author-name">Modell: '.$row["fahrzeugName"].'</span></h4>';
        }
// and so forth for all of your other cases
}
```

Comment: Hello and thank you. Im looking just for the $row not for the whole $output as I tried to explain in my example.
I'm giving this a try thank you!

Comment: I've tried editing my answer, perhaps better to correspond to what you are asking!